# Convert PyTeaser (python) Split Sentences method into C#

Tags: c#, python, regex

How can I accomplish the following python regular expression in C#?

```
regex_split(u'(?<![A-ZА-ЯЁ])([.!?]"?)(?=\s+\"?[A-ZА-ЯЁ])')
```

The general idea of what it does is splits a string of text (multiple paragraphs and sentences) into an array.

INPUT:

My name is Mark.  I have a cat and I live in the dark.  Sometimes I walk to the "scary park."  "It terrifies me", she said.

OUTPUT:

["My name is Mark", ".", "I have a cat and I live in the dark", ".", Sometimes I walk to the "scary park"", ".\"", "\"It terrifies me\", she said", "."]

I think that's the general idea of what it's meant to do.  Also if there are any line breaks it should also split on them.

I have managed to get the following together but I need to split on a new line also, "\r\n"

```
Regex.Split(content, @"(?<!Mr?s?|\b[A-Z])\.\s*");
```

How can I mimic the python reg exp in c#?

UPDATE
This has been carried out using reg exp in python, so I don't see why NLP is required

Comment: I don't get why this is off topic.  I'm asking for help with Regular expressions.

Comment: This is not a job for regex. Look for NLP library to achieve this.

Comment: @nhahtdh it is - regex is fine for the job.  There is a supplied python regular expression in my post, all I want to do is replicate that so that it works in C#.  What the regular expression used in python does is sufficient and therefore does not require NLP.

Comment: I suggest NLP library, because you are essentially duplicating the heuristics and patterns people have put together in a less complete form by writing regex. If you want a general solution for splitting sentence, it's best to use NLP library.

Comment: Yup I get that.  I'm working on version one at the moment, then if uptake is good I will work on perfecting it.  Thanks for the suggestion, I do agree that NLP is eventually the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match punctuation characters and split by that.

One possibility:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

String content = "My name is Mark. I have a cat and I live in 
the dark. Sometimes I walk to the \"scary park.\" \"It 
terrifies me\", she said.";

Regex.Split(content, @"(\s*\n\s*)|(([.?!])(?:""|(?:\s+)|$))");
```

Which gives:

> ```
> string[9] {  
>     "My name is Mark", ".",  
>     "I have a cat and I live in the dark", ".",  
>     "Sometimes I walk to the \"scary park\", ".",  
>     "\"It terrifies me\", she said", ".", ""
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. What's the output of that?  Does it put the punctuation in a separate element in the array?  I don't think it's that simple... I'm pretty sure I've tried it.  Plus, doesn't \w split by word?  I will try it when I get home unless you can check what the output is.

Comment: Also, there is nothing in the reg exp distinguishing between quotes at the end of the sentence or not.

Comment: Added result to answer.

Comment: Sorry, the sentence, "It terrifies me\", she said" shouldn't be split up... it should stay in tact... that's what I was meaning in the last comment.  Do you just need to add in \" after the \s?  UPDATE - no the \" doesn't fix it.

Comment: Answer updated. It should be good for you.

Comment: Great thanks, I will try it out tonight!  Could you explain what the reg ex is doing too.  As I really want to understand it rather than just copy and paste :)  Also, I noticed on your profile that you have python experience, does the reg exp that you have produced, mimic the original python one in my question?

Comment: what do you mean "wrongly quoted" ?

Comment: The other issue I'm having with the original one you supplied, is if a sentence has a comma in it, it's splitting it by that.  I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Forget my original regex, I missread your question on how you want to split. I said "wrongly quoted" because I'm used to see the dot after the end quote, but it seems the common way is before :)

Comment: So the new regex won't split on new lines now?  What if a sentence has U.S. - I don't want it to split on either of the .'s

Comment: Do you understand the python version, regex_split(u'(?<![A-ZА-ЯЁ])([.!?]"?)(?=\s+\"?[A-ZА-ЯЁ])') - if so can you replicate that?

Comment: Yes, I do understand your regex. Do you ? I'm not interested in fixing every scenario that won't fit, because it's impossible. Take what I gave you and tune it if needed. For instance, to ignore accronyms, simply force the regex to match the space after a dot: `(\.)(?:\s|"|$)`.

Comment: No I don't understand it, Regex isn't my strongest skill!  That's why I'm reaching out, but getting you to explain so I can learn.  I will give that one a go.  Thanks.

Comment: How do I handle \r\n in the text that's passed in, \s isn't catching it?!

Comment: `\s` catch \r\n, you can expand the regex to `(\.)(?:""|(?:\s+)|$)` so it will match a dot followed by many spaces. Could you please accept this answer ? If you need more help, post another question. I will give you 5mins in chat to clarify any last points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94839/discussion-between-cyrbil-and-dotnethaggis).

Comment: I can't join chat just now.  Off out.  I may offer a bounty tomorrow as I ideally want the python reg ex replicated...

Comment: That didn't work... for example, after split I'm left with the following sentence... Mike Ford saw Sam Burgess as a back-row forward in rugby union despite him playing at centre for England\r\nSam Burgess \"didn't have the stomach\" to fight for his future in rugby union, says Bath head coach Mike Ford - the \r\n hasn't been caught between "England" and "Sam"

Comment: Because your sentence **does not** contain any punctuation! I wont answer any more question as it will always brings new problems. StackOverflow is not a support for your lack of knowledge. It can be a guidance, but not a teacher. https://regex101.com/r/eO4vD3/1

Comment: That's exactly what it is for, people's lack of knowledge. But from it I'm going to go off and learn from it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I modified the last regex you provided.  It seems to be close to the original python one that I had in my post.  I can take it from here.  Thanks again for your help.